# inmethod-grid wicket , DataGrid how to catch event such as sort event and change data source model from another component

Tags: jakarta-ee, wicket, wicket-1.6, wicketstuff

Heloo i am using inmethod-grid components and I was wondering where can i catch the sort event in order for any time sort is called I want my com.inmethod.grid.datagrid to be renderd with the first page and not stayong on the current page 
in order to achive this I would like

1. someone know how I can catch this event without copying all the inmethod-grid  jar ?
2. how can I on the render event catch the component model and change it in order to restart, go to the first page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to

```
 @overide AbstractGrid.onSortStateChanged(AjaxRequestTarget target)
```

and there did my thing